# Python regex statement not returning correct results

Tags: python, regex

My regex syntax is not returning the correct results. I have data returned from GitHub using the github3.py library that returns three possible strings when parsing through the patch key of md files (https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files).  I've read the regex documentation and several threads, but I'm missing something in my syntax.

`string1 = '> [HELP.SELECTOR]'`
`string2 = '-> [HELP.SELECTOR]'`
`string3 = '+> [HELP.SELECTOR]'`

I want to print True for the exact match to `string2` or `string3` and False if `string1` is found.  My results are returning False if `string2` or `string3` is found.

```
for prs in repo.pull_requests():
    search_string_found = 'False'
    regex_search_string1 = re.compile(r"^\+>\s\[HELP.SELECTOR\]")
    regex_search_string2 = re.compile(r"^->\s\[HELP.SELECTOR\]")
    for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():
        match_text1 = regex_search_string1.search(data.patch)
        match_text2 = regex_search_string2.search(data.patch)                        
        if match_text1 is not None and match_text2 is not None:
            search_string_found = 'True'
            break

    print('HELP.SELECTOR present in file: ', search_string_found)
```

Comment: Just test against one regex: `regex_search_string = re.compile(r"^[+-]>\s\[HELP\.SELECTOR\]")`, then: `if regex_search_string.search(data.patch):`

Comment: Your solution worked.  I tweaked the regex by removing the caret and the correct results were returned.  `regex_search_string = re.compile(r"[\+-]>\s\[HELP\.SELECTOR\]")`.

Comment: That means the strings you needed were not at the start of the string, right?

Comment: `[+/-]` is at the start of the string, such as `+> [HELP.SELECTOR]`, but when I tested with the caret, incorrect results were coming back, but when I removed it, results were as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you confirm your strings may be not located at the string start, you need

```
regex_search_string = re.compile(r"[+-]>\s\[HELP\.SELECTOR\]")
for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():
    match_text = regex_search_string.search(data.patch)
    if match_text:
        search_string_found = 'True'
        break
```

Note:

- `[+-]` matches either a `+` or a `-` since it is a character class that matches a single character from a range/set specified inside it
- `+` inside `[...]` does not have to be escaped ever
- `-` at the start or end of `[...]` does not have to be escaped
- `re.search` returns a match data object or `None`, you need to check it first before accessing the text matched/captured

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to maintain one regex string than several. Try this:

```
import re

strings = [
     '> [HELP.SELECTOR]$',
     '-> [HELP.SELECTOR]$',
     '+> [HELP.SELECTOR]$',
]

for string in strings:
    print (bool(re.match(r'[-+]> \[HELP.SELECTOR\]$', string)), string)
```

Result:

```
False > [HELP.SELECTOR]
True -> [HELP.SELECTOR]
True +> [HELP.SELECTOR]
```

Applying that to your problem,

```
#UNTESTED
for prs in repo.pull_requests():
    search_string_found = any(
        re.match(r'[-+]> \[HELP.SELECTOR\]', data.patch)
        for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files())
    print('HELP.SELECTOR present in file: ', search_string_found)
```